# Insertion problem of unique ID row in laravel

Tags: php, database, postgresql, csv, laravel-5

I am trying to insert some csv data to a table named `tuhanorder`. I want to insert only those row whose `orderbango` is not inserted previously. here is my code

```
$orderhenkan=tuhanorder::firstOrCreate(['orderbango' => $orderbango],
                         ['juchukubun2'=> 'ヤマト運輸'],
                         ['soufusakibango'=> $syukkosakibango],
                         ['chumonsyabango'=>(!empty($thanerjonno))],
                         ['money2'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int17']))],
                         ['money3'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int18']))],
                         ['money5'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int19']))],
                         ['money4'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int31']))],
                         ['moneymax'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int30']))],
                         ['otodokedate'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int22']))],
                         ['youbou'=> $answers[$i]['int20']],
                         ['chumonsyajouhou'=> $answers[$i]['int21']],
                         ['otodoketime'=> $answers[$i]['int23']],
                         ['information4'=> $answers[$i]['int24']],
                         ['kessaihouhou'=> $answers[$i]['int25']],
                         ['juchubango'=> $answers[$i]['int0']],
                         ['chumondate'=> $answers[$i]['int1']],
                         ['information5'=>$answers[$i]['int2']],
                         ['juchukubun1'=> $answers[$i]['int10']]);
```

My code is working. But it is only inserting first two elements. Rest are null in database.I am using postgresql as database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First It's problem of mass assignment concept in Laravel. 
You have to specify your all table fields into $fillable array of Your Model (tuhanorder).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment

Second here I noted you are just checking condition but if condition match then you have to insert data something like this:

```
'money2'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int17']) ? $answers[$i]['int17'] : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. Here is my code

```
$tuhanorder=tuhanorder::firstOrCreate(['orderbango' => $orderbango],
                         ['juchukubun2'=> 'ヤマト運輸',
                           'soufusakibango'=> $syukkosakibango,
                           'chumonsyabango'=>(!empty($thanerjonno) ? $thanerjonno : null ),
                           'money2'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int17']) ? $answers[$i]['int17'] : null ),
                           'money3'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int19']) ? $answers[$i]['int19'] : null ),
                           'money5'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int18']) ? $answers[$i]['int18'] : null ),
                           'money4'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int31']) ? $answers[$i]['int31'] : null ),
                           'moneymax'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int30']) ? $answers[$i]['int30'] : null ),
                           'otodokedate'=>(!empty($answers[$i]['int22']) ? $answers[$i]['int22'] : null ),
                           'youbou'=> $answers[$i]['int20'],
                           'chumonsyajouhou'=> $answers[$i]['int21'],
                           'otodoketime'=> $answers[$i]['int23'],
                           'information4'=> $answers[$i]['int24'],
                           'kessaihouhou'=> $answers[$i]['int25'],
                           'juchubango'=> $answers[$i]['int0'],
                           'chumondate'=> $answers[$i]['int1'],
                           'information5'=>$answers[$i]['int2'],
                           'juchukubun1'=> $answers[$i]['int10']
                         ]);
```